# MySQL update overwrites collation

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, mysql, systemd

I recently added a new collation to MySQL as [outlined here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/full-text-adding-collation.html) for the purpose of including a dash `-` character in fulltext searches.  It worked fine but a couple of days later my changes were overwritten by the apt.systemd.daily Unattended-Upgrade routine (which btw, I had no idea existed).

My question:  Is there an upgrade-proof way to modify MySQL collation / charsets?  I understand some system files are not meant to be altered, but typically there would be an appropriate user configuration file where those changes can be applied.  Since I followed the official guidelines, I am surprised that these are files which would be replaced by an automatic system process.

**UPDATE:**
Just to be 100% clear I'm talking about edits made to the following two files (which are referenced in the article I linked above):

- /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml
- /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml

Comment: If true I would consider that a **bug**. Upgrades --never-- --ever-- should change table definitions. Never. That is user data and not system data so it has to be out of the reach of any form of updates. Things like that could break websites.  The only update that could mess with table is removal of a setting in a new release of MySQL but those always tend to be backwards compatible and are always manual edits we all need to make.

Comment: @Rinzwind - It absolutely **is** true, as I can see the application breaking the moment systemd ran the auto upgrade at around 4am last night.  And just to be clear we're talking about the files in `/usr/share/mysql/charsets`.

Comment: @Rinzwind - can you make a suggestion about who to go to for a definitive answer on this, and if it's a bug, where would I report it?  Would it be with the package maintainer?

Comment: **note:** this was addressed and closed in latest debian/ubuntu packages per [this bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84761)